# How do you add a class to a form_for helper in rails 3?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3

This is what i currently have in my form partial

```
<%= form_for @short, :html => {:class => "hello"} do |f| %>
```

and then in my css

```
#hello{
padding-top: 21px;
}
```

Does anyone know why this isnt working? I've seen this as an answer on several questions on here.

Please let me know if i can include anything else that might lead to figuring this out.

Css is included on the layout.html.erb page, I'm not really sure what else I can rule out.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy, in your css you need to write `.hello {}` for a class (a dot in front of your class name). `#` is for id's

Comment: what a fail, i think i got too worked up over getting the rails syntax that i completely over looked the css. Thank you very much